# How do I get Outlook (MSN) mail to work on iOS on my new Phone?

Tags: ios, mail.app, ms-office

I recently upgraded my iPhone and, as usually, all of my e-mail accounts transferred seamlessly when I restored my settings from a recent backup. All *except* my msn.com account. In this account's inbox there was just a single bizarre email:

[image]

Choosing "Continue using this email app" took me to a website claiming that my choice was confirmed, but no mail has showed up.

How do I get Outlook (MSN) mail to work on iOS on my new Phone?

Comment: what website is it

Comment: Can't you just delete the settings for msn.com from your iPhone and define the account again afterwards?